# Oracle Apex: load an application variable each time the application is loaded

Tags: oracle, events, plsql, oracle-apex

I need to do some refactoring for an Apex application and I would like to handle often used credentials as application variables.

Is there any event i could call a procedure every time the application is opend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an application computation that execute "on new instance" - so the moment a new session is allocated to your browser - even prior to login.

You could delay this computation until post-authentication (defined in your authentication scheme), or any application items that has not been evaluated to Y or N. Just ensure they can't be set from the browser.

In each application's security attributes, you can define 'Initialisation PL/SQL' to execute on every page render, depending on what it is you're actually doing.